# can pfSense captive portal grant internet access to IP which is assigned by Windows DHCP server only?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, pfsense, captive-portal

In our organization we have a wifi access point and IP addresses are assigned by a Windows DHCP server. We have MAC filtering enabled for internet access in the DHCP server but the issue is that if anyone configure static IP address then he can also access the internet, which we want to restrict. I want to configure any captive portal which can only grant access to IP  addresses which are assigned by the DHCP server.

Can pfSense captive portal grant internet access to IP addresses which are assigned by the Windows DHCP server only??

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to have multiple WiFi networks. It depends on the type/brand of Access points You have. Enterprise models normally can handle 4 different networks. Allow anyone with the correct CSID and credentials to use Network 1 (i.e. give access to 10.0.1.0/24). Configure another WiFi network 2 with another CSID connected to lets say 10.0.2.0/24.

Configure the firewall to block internet access from Wifi Network 2, and allow from Wifi Network 1.

Now this solutions does not use captive portal at all, but this should also be possible in PFSense Captive portal out-of-the-box. According to [PFSense doc](https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/book/captiveportal/mac-address-control.html)
you can filter on MAC addresses and select *PASS* or *BLOCK* according to your need.

The captive portal can either/or filter on IP addresses and MAC addresses.